# Show only strings with value between 2 user input numbers

Tags: c#, string

I have 600 lines in strings, all are numbered ex:

```
contents[0] = "HALTUNG;" + textBox2.Text + "-01" + " " + textBox2.Text + "-02;" + textBox2.Text + "-01;" + textBox2.Text + "-02";
contents[1] = "HALTUNG;" + textBox2.Text + "-02" + " " + textBox2.Text + "-03;" + textBox2.Text + "-02;" + textBox2.Text + "-03";
contents[2] = "HALTUNG;" + textBox2.Text + "-03" + " " + textBox2.Text + "-04;" + textBox2.Text + "-03;" + textBox2.Text + "-04";
contents[3] = "HALTUNG;" + textBox2.Text + "-04" + " " + textBox2.Text + "-05;" + textBox2.Text + "-04;" + textBox2.Text + "-05";
contents[4] = "HALTUNG;" + textBox2.Text + "-05" + " " + textBox2.Text + "-06;" + textBox2.Text + "-05;" + textBox2.Text + "-06";
contents[5] = "HALTUNG;" + textBox2.Text + "-06" + " " + textBox2.Text + "-07;" + textBox2.Text + "-06;" + textBox2.Text + "-07";
```

I want to write to file the strings between 2 user input number ex: (2-8) or (1-250)
How can i do it?

Thanks

Comment: i have not the slightest clue what you want... do you want to write arrayElements between some user-input values?

Comment: Please tell me you didn't actually type out 600 string assignments?

Comment: Getting paid by the line of code?

Answer (score 1):

You can use linq [Skip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [Take](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, I assum Start has starting line number and End has ending line Number.

```
var lines = contents.Skip(Start).Take(End-Start);
```

Comment: That is exactely what i was looking for, Thanks!